# Fakeraid with dualboot, order of installation of windows and linux

Tags: dual-boot, raid, amd-processor

I have three hdd disks that I intended to use as raid0 as a single data disk (for video editing) and a dual boot installation, with Windows 10 pro and ubuntu 17.10 on a small SSD.

I thought that using the storage pool tool of Windows would be enough, but I get very disappointing read speed by using it (it's the same speed of a single disk).

So I'm thinking on reinstalling both Ubuntu and Windows with the fakeraid provided by my Asus X370 Prime (ryzen 1700). I would install the OSes on the SSD though, not on the RAID setup.

Do I need to install Ubuntu after Windows as I read this on some tutorial online? (but for installing the OS on the raid disk).

Comment: >I get very disappointing read speed by using it (it's the same speed of a single disk). raid0 can't increase the read speed much tho. try raid1.

Comment: >fakeraid provided by my Asus X370 Prime (ryzen 1700), it will probsbly be transparent, so do it as you do with a non-raid setup.

Comment: Raid1 has a similar disappointing speed just like raid0. Only Raid5 achieves at least double the speed of one disk (400MB/S), but I don't like to have worse writing speeds.

Comment: this says raid1 is faster than raid0, https://calomel.org/zfs_raid_speed_capacity.html @franzlorenzon, why doesn't @ work?

Comment: I don't know. But I reinstalled Windows with fakeraid and now it's perfect (600MB/S). Next thing to do is reinstall ubuntu 17.10:)